# How do I delete a folder but not the contents?

Tags: directory, rm

My directory (in Linux) looks like `com/com/{various,files}` where `com` and `com` are folders of the same name and the second `com` holds the various files. I want the first `com` removed, but the second and files in the second kept.

Comment: `mv com COM; mv COM/com com; rmdir COM`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the outer directory out of the way, move the inner one to the name you want, and then delete the (now empty) outer directory:

```
$ mv com to-delete
$ mv to-delete/com com
$ rmdir to-delete
```

You could also `mv com/com/* com` and remove the inner directory, if you don't have too many files and none of them are dotfiles, but the above is more general and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this is to move the "various files" up a level and then remove the second "com" directory.

#### Example

```
$ mv com/com/(various files) com/.
$ rmdir com/com
```

Answer (score 0):

So here you have this all in one:-

```
mv com/com/ SOME-TEMPORARY-NAME ; rm -rf com ; mv SOME-TEMPORARY-NAME com
```

The `;` simply lets you run all the commands in one go.

And then I have used `rm -rf` so that even if you have any other files inside `com/` all will be removed without user-interaction.

Comment: You've been around long enough that you should know: one or two line answers are not considered terribly helpful. Consider expanding your post with some explanation or documentation (or perhaps reasoning for the `-rf` there).

Comment: @HalosGhost Sorry, short question, short answer ;) . I have updated the answer now.