# How do I delete a folder but only keep selected files?

Tags: bash, directory, rm, mv

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Photos
|
|---> 2015-08-23
      |
      |---> IMG_0019.JPG           // keep
            IMG_0019.JPG.json      // toss
            IMG_0020.JPG           // keep
            IMG_0020.JPG.json      // toss
            IMG_0021.JPG           // keep
            IMG_0021.JPG.json      // toss
            metadata.json          // toss

      2015-08-24
      |
      |---> IMG_0242.MP4           // keep
            IMG_0242.MP4.json      // toss
            metadata.json          // toss

      2015-08-25
      |
      |---> IMG_0243.MOV           // keep
            IMG_0243.MOV.json      // toss
            IMG_0243(1).MOV        // keep
            IMG_0243(1).MOV.json   // toss
            IMG_0244.PNG           // keep
            IMG_0019.PNG.json      // toss
            metadata.json          // toss
```

This goes on and on. My goal is to end up with a folder structure like so

```
Photos
|
|--> IMG_0019.JPG
     IMG_0020.JPG
     IMG_0021.JPG
     IMG_0242.MP4
     IMG_0243.MOV
     IMG_0243(1).MOV
     IMG_0244.PNG
     ...
```

I was looking into to doing a modified version of this [article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153241/how-do-i-delete-a-folder-but-not-the-contents)
where I would loop through each directory and perform a regex to only grab file of value. Something like:

```
// get a list of all directories
// loop through directories
//     get all contents in directory
//     loop through all contents in directory
//        determine if file is of value (ie. MP4, PNG, MOV, JPG, etc.)
//        move selected file out to parent directory
//        remove directory
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have two subdirectories with the same name in the same parent directory? Also, the list of files that you have in your expected result don't match what you have marked as `keep` in the current structure.

Comment: Yes. This file structure is from google photos. So I would have both `2016-02-17` and `2016-02-17 #2`.

Comment: Sorry yes you are correct about the expected result vs marked as ```keep```. I will fix that. I was just using that as an example

Comment: You cannot have two folders in the same path with the same name. Is the second one actually called `2015-08-24 # 2`?

Comment: Yes its actually called ```2015-08-24 #2```

Comment: Now that I think about it, I can manually go through and combine the 20 or directories that have the ```#2```

Comment: So then one directory is called `2015-08-24 # 2` and the other is `2015-08-24`. You need to be clear on that because it looks like you are stating that there are two directories with the same exact name in the same path.

Comment: Just updated the article. I removed the reference to the same exact naming issue. Sorry for the confusion. Ill manually go back and clean up the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your the structure in the expected result, you just want to keep the files that don't end in `.json`. This will do it:

```
cd Photos
find . -type f ! -name *.json -exec mv {} . \; && rm -rf 2015*
```

From inside of the Photos directory, you find the files that don't end in `.json`, move them into `.` or the current directory, and then delete the subdirectories and the files inside that you don't want. You can also use `rm -ri 2015*` so that it will prompt you before removing each directory or run the `find` and `rm` commands separately in case you change your mind before deleting the rest of the files and their directories.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks

Comment: @Jghorton14 You are welcome.